# Working with heatmap2 function in R. Getting Error Message: Error in par(op): invalid value for graphic parameter pin

Tags: r, heatmap

I am working with heat map in R and using heatmap2 function to create a correlation heat map. I created a heat map last night and it was just fine. I only missed to add one variable "Sports Involvement" and came back to add it and now it isn't working and showing me this error:

Error in .External.graphics(C_layout, num.rows, num.cols, mat, as.integer(num.figures),  :
invalid graphics state
Error in par(op) : invalid value specified for graphical parameter "pin"

Here is my code:

```
labvec <- c(rep("ACE Score"))

labvec[c("Bully-Victim","Family Resilience",
     "TBI","Child's Sex","Child's Age",
     "Child's Race","Caregiver Education","Sports 
Involvement","Epilepsy 
Status", "Percent FPL")] <- c("Bully-Victim","Family Resilience",                                                                                  
"TBI","Child's Sex","Child's Age",                                                                               
"Child's Race","Caregiver Education","Sports Involvement","Epilepsy 
 Status", "Percent FPL")

     heatmap.2(acenation[,-1], cellnote = acenation[,-1], notecol 
     = "black", key.xlab = "r value",
      trace = "none",
      par(cex.main=0.8),
      dendrogram = "column", density.info = "none", cexCol =1.3, 
     cexRow = 1.3,
      Rowv = NA,
      margins = c(15,15),
      labRow = labvec,
      main = "Correlation Matrix Between ACE Score, TBI and Covariates",
      scale= "none",col= brewer.pal(8, "Greens"))
```

I created multiple heat maps with this code several times after I cracked this two months ago. However, it isn't working now. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this problem; please edit your question to share your data, create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and/or perhaps try decreasing your margins (e.g. try `margins = c(5,5)`?)

Comment: I tried decreasing margins but still seeing the error. I also edited my question and the code. Can you see if it is reproducible now? Thanks for your response!!

Comment: For the question to be reproducible you need to provide example input data (i.e. edit your question to include the output of the command `dput(acenation)`). Another suggestion is to type `dev.off()` before trying to plot (per https://stackoverflow.com/q/18350353/12957340) and/or instead of `labvec <- c(rep("ACE Score"))` try `labvec <- c("ACE Score" = "ACE Score")`